# screen behind rate limited iptables and connection disconnects

Tags: iptables

Take this scenario if I have rate limited the connections to 4.(i.e if you attempt 4th connection you wont be able to login for some time.)
If in a minute I get disconnected 3 times
while I was already logged in on the server with a screen session,
will I be able to login or I need to keep quite for a minute?

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 4 --name DEFAULT --rsource -j DROP
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name DEFAULT --rsource
```

Comment: What's stopping you trying that by yourself right now? Just curious. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to make a new SSH connection a fourth time within the time limit, that connection is dropped whether you're using screen or not.  Only new connections would be affected, so if you're actually still connected on an old connection, that connection would still be good.